# How to fill color map with a json from api url?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I load a map with a json file which loads data with topojson to generate it.
Then I need to color the states with `.attr("fill")`. Here, I call an async function that returns values with colors. In the console log the value is returned, but in html it's a promise object.

How can i resolve that?

```
d3.json("/states.json", function (error, us) {
    if (error) throw error;

g.append("g")
    .attr("id", "states")
    .selectAll("path")
    .data(topojson.feature(us, us.objects.states).features)
    .enter()
    .append("path")
    .attr("d", path)
    .on("click", clicked)
    .on("load", getTotal())
    .attr("fill", async function (d) {
        var value = await getValues(d.properties.IN1)
        console.log(value[0].color)
        return value[0].color;
    });
});

async function getValues(state_id) {
    let response = await fetch("/api/" + state_id);
    let data = await response.json();
    return data;
}
```